# DataBinding XML - Cannot bind to datasource

Tags: c#, xml, data-binding

I'm testing very simple DataBinding with XML and I'm having trouble when the XML has ChildNodes deeper than 2 levels.

I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Cannot bind to the property or column
>   SecondLevel/SecondNode1 on the DataSource. Parameter name: dataMember'

I am not using and XSD schema file, but it is not a problem for me to do so if it is helpful.

This is my XML content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sample xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<MainNode>
    <SubNode1>basic string</SubNode1>
    <SubNode2>0</SubNode2>
    <SubNode3>true</SubNode3>
    <SecondLevel>
        <SecondNode1>another string</SecondNode1>
        <SecondNode2>1</SecondNode2>
        <SecondNode3>false</SecondNode3>
    </SecondLevel>
</MainNode>
</sample>
```

And this is my C# code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // load the file
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml("sample.xml");

    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

    //bs.DataSource = ds;
    //bs.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName; //main node
    bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    //bs.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName; //main node

    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "SubNode1");
    comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", bs, "SubNode2");
    checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "SubNode3");

    //Error happens below
    textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bs, "SecondLevel/SecondNode1");
    //comboBox2.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", bs, "SecondLevel/SecondNode2");
    //checkBox2.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bs, "SecondLevel/SecondNode3");
}
```

Also, if you could point me to a way to make this two-way, it would help!
Thanks.

Comment: When using the DataSource ReadXml method the first tag is the dataset  name.  The second level tag is the DataTable names. Third layer is the Column names.  Fourth layer is the row data.  When you have more than 4 layers the ReadXml layer create a bunch of fractured tables that you cannot recombine nor use.  So it is best to create a custom xml parser to put data in a usable format.  In your case it looks like the data is being put into the 4th table  So use ds.Tables[3].

Comment: @jdweng  I just tried using ds.Tables[4] = Error cannot find Table 3. Tried [4], same thing - cannot find...

Comment: You are right.  sample is the dataset name and MainNode is the only table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

Here's the revised code that works - basically, I removed the BindingSource,
and used the DataSet directly (Duh!)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // load the file
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ds.ReadXml("sample.xml");

    // Removed usage of BindingSource
    // BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    // bs.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[0], "SubNode1");
    comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", ds.Tables[0], "SubNode2");
    checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("Checked", ds.Tables[0], "SubNode3");

    // Error fixed when using ds directly
    textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds.Tables[1], "SecondNode1");
    comboBox2.DataBindings.Add("SelectedIndex", ds.Tables[1], "SecondNode2");
    checkBox2.DataBindings.Add("Checked", ds.Tables[1], "SecondNode3");
}
```